# How can one visual a transformation which affects a component of density matrix?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

How to visualize a transformation that looks like $$\rho = \frac{\textbf{I} + r_1 \sigma_1 + r_2 \sigma_2 + r_3 \sigma_3}{2} \rightarrow \frac{\textbf{I} + r_1 \sigma_1 + \lambda ~r_2 \sigma_2 + r_3 \sigma_3}{2},$$
where $\lambda$ is real? What happens on the Bloch sphere under this transformation?

Comment: a stretch/contraction in the $y$ direction. This won't correspond to a physical transformation though

Comment: Thanks @gls. Is there a mathematical way of understanding this "stretch/contraction"?

Comment: define "mathematical way". You mean like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)?